# Get the longest ranges per seqnames

Tags: r, bioconductor, genomicranges

I have a `GRanges` object with different genomic ranges for each `seqnames` (e.g. chromosomes).
How can I get a `GRanges` containing only the longest range for each seqname/chromosome?

For example, if `gr` is a `GRanges`:

```
library(GenomicRanges)

# Make a GRanges object
set.seed(123)
gr <- GRanges(seqnames = rep(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"), times=2:4),
              ranges = IRanges(start=sample.int(10000, 9), 
                               width = c(3,5,50,20,10,500,100,500,200)))

# Add a column with the width for clarity:
mcols(gr)$width <- width(gr)

gr
#GRanges object with 9 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#      seqnames    ranges strand |     width
#         <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
#  [1]     chr1 2463-2465      * |         3
#  [2]     chr1 2511-2515      * |         5
#  [3]     chr2 8718-8767      * |        50
#  [4]     chr2 2986-3005      * |        20
#  [5]     chr2 1842-1851      * |        10
#  [6]     chr3 9334-9833      * |       500
#  [7]     chr3 3371-3470      * |       100
#  [8]     chr3 4761-5260      * |       500
#  [9]     chr3 6746-6945      * |       200
#  -------
#  seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

Then I want to obtain the following `GRanges`:

```
#GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#    seqnames      ranges strand |     width
#       <Rle>   <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
#  [1]     chr1 2511-2515      * |         5
#  [2]     chr2 8718-8767      * |        50
#  [3]     chr3 9334-9833      * |       500
```

For my application I'm OK with getting only the first longest range for `chr3` but I would appreciate a solution that can also select all ties if any.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
library(GenomicRanges)

# Make the GRanges object
set.seed(123)
gr <- GRanges(seqnames = rep(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"), times=2:4),
              ranges = IRanges(start=sample.int(10000, 9), 
                               width = c(3,5,50,20,10,500,100,500,200)))

# Add a column with the width for clarity:
mcols(gr)$width <- width(gr)

# split gr by seqnames
grl <- split(gr, seqnames(gr))

# Get the width of each range organized as an IntegerList
wgr <- width(grl)
# if gr is ordered by seqnames this is equivalent to:
wgr <- splitAsList(width(gr), seqnames(gr))
wgr
#IntegerList of length 3
#[["chr1"]] 3 5
#[["chr2"]] 50 20 10
#[["chr3"]] 500 100 500 200

# Get the ranges with the largest width
# See ?'which.max,NumericList-method' for the global argument
longestRanges <- gr[which.max(wgr, global = TRUE)]

longestRanges
#GRanges object with 3 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#      seqnames      ranges strand |     width
#         <Rle>   <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
#  [1]     chr1 2511-2515      * |         5
#  [2]     chr2 8718-8767      * |        50
#  [3]     chr3 9334-9833      * |       500
#  -------
#  seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

Note that this solution only works if the ranges in `gr` are initially grouped/ordered by `seqnames`.
If they are not, it is necessary to start by sorting `gr` with `gr <- sort(gr)`

To get all the ties, one can use:

```
longestRanges <- unlist(grl[which(wgr == max(wgr))])

longestRanges
#GRanges object with 4 ranges and 1 metadata column:
#       seqnames    ranges strand |     width
#          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> | <integer>
#  chr1     chr1 2511-2515      * |         5
#  chr2     chr2 8718-8767      * |        50
#  chr3     chr3 9334-9833      * |       500
#  chr3     chr3 4761-5260      * |       500
#  -------
#  seqinfo: 3 sequences from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```